# angularjs dropdown not closing when another opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a custom directive of a dropdown . 
Here is my code : https://plnkr.co/edit/YqJ6tz4fwvBRmtmzeCJr

To close the dropdown I'm checking the click event outside of that directive element.

```
 $document.bind('click', function() {
    scope.closeDropdown();
  });
```

But the problem with this code is when one dropdown is opened and another one is click the first one doesn't close .

How to close the dropdown when another one is clicked ?
One way I could do this by declaring a varible in the controller and check everytime before opening the dropdown. But in this way this directive can't be use independently .

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ng-class for adding class 'show' which makes  display block

Updated template

```
<div class="selector">
 <div class="box-container">
   <input type="text" class="search search-input" placeholder="{{dname}}" isDropDownInput="true" ng-model="userInput" />
  <ul class="dropdown-list" ng-class="{show:showDropDown}">
     <li ng-repeat="value in data | filter:userInput track by $index">
        <span >
            <input class="check-select" type="checkbox" value="{{value}}" ng-click="toggleCheck(value)" isdropdown="true" ng-checked="isChecked(value)"/> 
            {{value }}
         </span>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Use controller for toggling the class when user clicks on window object, here is the updated script,

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
// safeApply service, courtesy Alex Vanston and Andrew Reutter
.factory('safeApply', [function ($rootScope) {
   return function ($scope, fn) {
    var phase = $scope.$root.$$phase;
    if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
        if (fn) {
            $scope.$eval(fn);
        }
    } else {
        if (fn) {
            $scope.$apply(fn);
        } else {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    }
}
}])
.directive('dropDown', dropDown);

 function dropDown($document) {
  var directive = {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
          dname: '@',
          data: '=',
          selected : '=choices',
      },
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      link: linker,
      controller: dropdownController
  };
  return directive;

  function dropdownController($scope, $rootScope, $window, safeApply){

    $window.onclick = function(event){
      console.log("event target = " + event.target.attributes);
        if(event.target.attributes && event.target.attributes.isDropDownInput){
          $rootScope.$broadcast("closeAllDropDown", {'isDropDownInput':true, 'inputId':event.target.attributes.placeHolder.nodeValue})
        }
        else if(event.target.attributes && !event.target.attributes.isDropDown){
          $rootScope.$broadcast("closeAllDropDown", {'isDropDownInput':false})
        }
      };

      $scope.$on("closeAllDropDown", function(event,payload){
        console.log("eventObj = " + event, payload.isDropDownInput);
        if(payload.isDropDownInput){
          if(event.currentScope.dname == payload.inputId){
            event.currentScope.showDropDown = true;
          }
          else{
             event.currentScope.showDropDown = false;
          }
        }
        else{
          $scope.showDropDown = false;
        }
        safeApply($scope);
        console.log('$scope.showDropDown = ' + $scope.showDropDown)
      });

      $scope.openDropDown = function () {

         $scope.showDropDown = true;
      };


      $scope.closeDropdown = function () {
          $scope.showDropDown = false;
      };
      $scope.toggleCheck = function(item){  
        $scope.showDropDown = true;
          if($scope.multiSelect){
              $scope.multiChoice(item);
          }else{
              $scope.singleChoice(item);
          }
      };

      $scope.isChecked = function (item) {
          if ($scope.selected.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      };

      $scope.singleChoice = function(item) {
          $scope.selected.length = 0;
          $scope.selected.push(item);
      };

      $scope.multiChoice = function (item) {
          var index = $scope.selected.indexOf(item);

          if(index > -1){
              $scope.selected.splice(index, 1);
          }else {
              $scope.selected.push(item);
          }
      };

      $scope.removeItem = function(item){
          $scope.selected.splice($scope.selected.indexOf(item), 1);         
      };
  }

  function linker(scope, elem, attr) {
      console.log('dropdown::loaded');
      scope.showDropDown = false;
      scope.selected = [];

      scope.multiSelect = 'multiselect' in attr;


     }
  }
 dropDown.$inject = ['$document'];
})();
```

Hope it helps rather than using JQUERY

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution... working perfectly .I think using of ng-show would be better than ng-class .

Comment: However there is one problem with this solution , the dropdown closes when you click inside it . Could you fix this ?

Comment: hope updated code will work. While broadcasting event we can ignore checkbox click by adding a attribute on checkbox, also we can initiate digest cycle by safely calling apply() when digest cycle is not in progress using factory provided by courtesy Alex Vanston and Andrew Reutter

Comment: Thanks....great solution . Could you provide link where can I find more information about calling digest cycle using factory .

Comment: Well you can refer this https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/ to understand more about digest cycle, how inbuilt angular directives triggers digest cycle automatically and when to manually initiate digest cycle using apply

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is:

```
 scope.toggleCheck = function(item,element){
                scope.closeDropdown();
                if(scope.multiSelect){
                    scope.multiChoice(item);
                }else{
                    scope.singleChoice(item);
                }
            };
```

or a better waY:

```
 scope.openDropDown = function () {
                $('.dropdown-list').css('display','none');
                elem.find('.dropdown-list').css('display','block');
            };
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/zwTjiktY8H3HmHnvQnoa?p=preview

Comment: Could you suggest me how can I improve this directive ?

Comment: i don't have extensive knowledge of angular,so i can't help you there